# $H^{1/2}$ function but not better

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for an example of a function $f: [0, 1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is in the Sobolev space of order $1/2$, $H^{1/2}([0, 1])$, but not in the Sobolev space of order $1/2 + \varepsilon$, for any $\varepsilon$.

Functions with discontinuities like the Rectangular function or the sawtooth wave are in the Sobolev spaces of order $s< 1/2$, but not equal to $s$.

Comment: For $s>1/2$, the space $H^s$ embeds into  $C^\alpha$ with $\alpha = 1/2-1/s$. So, any $H^{1/2}$ function that is not H&ouml;lder continuous will do the job. Depending on the definition of $H^{1/2}$ you are using, you may want to try something like $1/\log (x/2)$, or a  Fourier series.

Comment: @CareBear : My previous comment was not stated correctly, and had the range backwards in $r$. You want $\{ a_{n}\}$ so that  $\sum_{n}|n|^{r}|a_{n}|^{2} < \infty$ for $r=1$ but not for any $r > 1$. What I was getting at was that you're looking for a borderline case of convergence of a sum that is 'best' in regard to powers; I don't believe I've ever seen such a case. Cases where there is convergence for $0 < r < 1$ but not for $r=1$ are easier, but not this other case.